# Is it proper to create new kafka consumer for each client?

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I'm running a websocket server for realtime data streaming and using kafka for stream processing. Here is it good practice to create new kafka consumer for each client?
As of now I'm creating a new kafka consumer for each client but if I added more than 5000 clients I'm getting this error:

> %2|1683792545.811|THREAD|rdkafka#consumer-13806| [thrd:main]: Unable to create broker thread

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
func(c *Client) SendDataTOConsumer() {  
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            log.Println("PANIC:", r)
        }
    }()
    
    run := true
    config := &kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092", // broker addr
        "group.id": c.Id, // consumer group
        "auto.offset.reset": "earliest", // earliest offset
    }

    // Create Kafka consumer
    consumer, err := kafka.NewConsumer(config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }

    defer func ()  {
        consumer.Close()
    }()

    var topic []string
    for key := range c.SubsTopics {
        topic = append(topic, key)
    }

    if err := consumer.SubscribeTopics(topic, nil); err != nil{
        log.Print("Error Subscribing topics: " ,err)
    }

    // Process messages
    for run {
        select {
        case unSubscribe := <- c.UnsubChan:
            run = false
            if unSubscribe {
                if err := consumer.Unsubscribe(); err != nil{
                    log.Println("Error while unsubscribing",err)
                }
            }
        
        default:
            message, err := consumer.ReadMessage(100 * time.Millisecond)
            if err != nil {
                // Errors are informational and automatically handled by the consumer
                continue
            }

            if err := c.Conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message.Value); err != nil {
                //close the connection, consumer and stop the for loop if some error occurs while writing the message
                if websocket.IsUnexpectedCloseError(err, websocket.CloseGoingAway, websocket.CloseAbnormalClosure, websocket.CloseNormalClosure){
                    break
                }
                run = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how im creating new consumer for each client.

Can anyone suggest me good practice to use kafka consumer for consuming message in Go.

Comment: Pulsar has a native websocket protocol. And Kafka compatibility... Why not use that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating kafka consumer per client, you can create one kafka consumer listening to all topics.
For each message from a topic, find out which clients should this message be sent and handle that way.

Comment: That's not really recommended, either. Especially if one topic has millions of records while others don't... Lag will delay processing records from less populated topics. Also, it'll consume data not meant for any currently subscribed websocket client

Comment: But What if the data should be streamed in real time low latency like share market data, will it be appropriate to find each message belongs to which client and send the message to client? I mean if there are 2 topics are there and 100000 clients are there and check each messages and send to every client.

Comment: if you have 2 topics and 100K clients, then you can run 10 copies of an application. each application copy sends data to 10k clients.

Comment: @OneCricketeer if topic load is not divided equally, then we can control what topics and application can listen to and design that way.
What I mean to say is OP's approach of one consumer per client will not work, when clients count can go upto 100k. Some intermediate components need to consume one copy of data from kafka, then loop over clients and sent to them.

Comment: Sure, but even so, 2 topics with 1 partition each, for example, cannot have more than 2 consumers. Number of records in the topic means nothing, and there's no guarantee it'll be evenly divided dataset over each topic... Those are Kafka basics. Your comment mentioned nothing about addressing lag or how to selectively forward data to subscribed websocket clients

Comment: hmm, OP said 1 msg to be sent to 100K client, so no need of consumer group or partition, each msg goes to every subscribed ws client.     
address lag - instead of 1 application process sending to 100k client (much slow), we can divide the clients among 10 copies of application. each app then has to send to only 10k client (much faster)
selectively forward - map<topic, list_of_ws_client> should be easy to maintain.

Comment: see firebase does something very similar here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/real-time_queries_at_scale#understand_high_write_traffic_in_the_system and https://firebase.google.com/static/docs/firestore/images/changelog_architecture.svg